# Автоматическое изменение данных через время MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть ли такая возможность, как изменение какого-то поля в таблице БД через какое-то время, средствами sql? 
Например: изменение какого-то значения поля таблицы через неделю, а еще через неделю обратно

Comment: только через планировщики задач, внешние (cron) или внутренние (event). Но лучше спроектировать БД так что бы изменение чего либо по времени было не нужно

Comment: @andrew-dmitriev какую версию MySQL используете?

Comment: @Mike да, жаль только в реальности не всегда получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Планировщик заданий, вот пример http://blog.nagaychenko.com/2009/11/30/scheduler-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-event-%D0%B2-mysql-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F-cron/
если есть навароты типа "через какое-то время" после, например, добавления записи, то делаем отдельную вспомогательную таблицу для контроля выполнения задач планировщиком.

Comment: Спасибо,даже не знал о такой фиче)